# My bubble chart extends well past the maxValue, and below the minValue

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

As shown in the demo, the maxValue is set to 2017, but the chart goes all the way to 2020.

How can I make the chart actually stop at 2017? It's taking up a bit too much space on my page so I want to optimize it

[See demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZK6Am/)

hAxis options look like this:

```
      hAxis: {
          'format':'####',
          maxValue: 2017,
          minValue: 2009
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
    viewWindowMode: "maximized"
```

to your "hAxis" block. Unfortunately that won't change the overall size of the chart. To change the overall chart size, you can use the "chartArea" blocK:

```
    chartArea: {
      width: "50%" // or whatever
    }
```

Comment: I can't get "px" chart area widths to do anything for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, this changed the max value to actually be 2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and `hAxis.viewWindow.max` options:

```
hAxis: {
    format: '####',
    viewWindow: {
       min: 2009,
       max: 2017
    }
}
```

Comment: yea this seems to work too, but it doesn't alter the chart size.

Comment: Hi, this caused the chart not to work, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK6Am/